# unable to install package datasets using pip and pip3

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am not able to install `datasets` package in intelliJ using pip

[image]

I tried updating setup_tols as follows, but no luck

```
easy_install -U setuptools
```

Same issue is there when I use pip3 in terminal as shown below

[image]

Please help !

Answer (score 1):

`setup.py` from PyPI tries to open `DESCRIPTION.rst` but there is no such file in the distribution. Clearly a bug in the package.

The [code at Github](https://github.com/realtimeweb/datasets) doesn't have `setup.py` at all. It's not an installable package.

PS. Please don't post images — post text.

Comment: thanks a lot , I will not post images from next time. Can you please let me know how can I download this package as this one don't have setup.py

Comment: Clone it with `git` or download a zip archive (see the button "Clone or download"). I see a `makefile` there so try running `make`.

Comment: I had following error running make
 amar@admin:~/Downloads/datasets-master$ make
python builder/builder.py -l java specs/.corgis ./datasets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "builder/builder.py", line 17, in <module>
    import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
make: *** [java] Error 1

Comment: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hm/40wvfw514611psdffd2gfxdw0000gn/T/pip-build-5c41nml_/datasets/